# Choose form at opening

Tags: powerapps

I created two form in powerapps. In SharePointIntegration.OnNew, I used NewForm(BudgetForm). Now, I want to open the other forms. So I change BudgetForm to Form1 (my new one).

But, when I create a new document, it still opens BudgetForm.
How can I open a different form ?

Thanks!

Comment: I find a way, using OnStart and put Navigate(Form1;Cover), but it seems not correct to do this like that. It's the best solution ?

Comment: It is correct, NewForm only changes the Form control's mode, if the form is on another screen, you need to manually navigate to that screen.